# Analog of an open map for uniform structures

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, uniform-spaces

In topology, a function is *continuous* if the *inverse image* of an open set is open.
A function is *open* if the *image* of an open set is open.

Uniformity continuity can be defined in a similar way as continuity.
A map $f$ between two uniform spaces is *uniformly continuous* if the *inverse image* (under $f \times f$) of an entourage is an entourage.

Now consider the following "uniform analog" of openness: the *image* (under $f \times f$) of an entourage is an entourage.

**Question**. Was this property studied? And if yes, is there a well-established name for it?

Motivation. I need this property in a very special case and I am looking for references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maps in question appear to be *uniformly open surjections*. I believe that uniformly open maps were introduced in E. Michael, [‘Topologies on spaces of subsets’](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1951-071-01/S0002-9947-1951-0042109-4/), Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. $\mathbf{71}$ ($1951$), $152$-$182$. If $\langle X,\mathscr{U}\rangle$ and $\langle Y,\mathscr{V}\rangle$ are uniform spaces, a map $f:X\to Y$ is *uniformly open* if for each $U\in\mathscr{U}$ there is a $V\in\mathscr{V}$ such that $f[U[x]]\supseteq V[f(x)]$ for each $x\in X$.

Suppose that $f$ is a uniformly open surjection, $U\in\mathscr{U}$, and $V\in\mathscr{V}$ is such that $f[U[x]]\supseteq V[f(x)]$ for each $x\in X$. Let $\langle y_0,y_1\rangle\in V$; then there are $x_0,x_1\in X$ such that $f(x_i)=y_i$ for $i=0,1$ and $\langle x_0,x_1\rangle\in U$, so $V\subseteq(f\times f)[U]$, and hence $(f\times f)[U]\in\mathscr{V}$.

I’ve not read the paper, but Vitaly V. Fedorchuk & Hans-Peter A. Künzi, [‘Uniformly open mappings and uniform embeddings of functions spaces’](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686419400023V), Topology and its Applications $\mathbf{61}$ ($1995$), $61$-$84$ appears to discuss them in considerable detail.